# Regarding childs visa

Tags: visas, uk, children, family

Apologies if this has been answered before.

I have applied for a standard Visit visa to travel to UK. And I gave the details of my spouse children who would be joining during my trip. And I did mention that they would travel with me and entered their passport numbers as well in my visa application. Now, I am wondering I need to fill up a separate visa application for all of them as well OR we will get a collective decision.

Please clarify the matter.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A visa is individual

You will need to fill separate application for every person that requires it

[UKVI](https://www.gov.uk/apply-to-come-to-the-uk/prepare-your-application)

> If you have dependants who want to come to the UK with you, each person will need to apply and pay separately.